# A more readable way of writing the following SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I'm going through [Stanford's DB class](http://www.db-class.org/course/class/index), and on one of the questions we are given the following [database](http://www.db-class.org/course/resources/index?page=moviedata). Now, I've already gotten my code to work, but it strikes me as terribly inefficient. We're using SQLite to execute our queries.

Is there any way I can write the following in a more fluid and readable manner? Specifically, I hate having to copy and paste my Averages table in twice.

The following isn't exact code per se because I don't want to break honor code. However, I have an Averages table, and everywhere where Averages shows up below, I am literally copy and pasting the entire SELECT query. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
SELECT avgbefore-avgafter
FROM

(SELECT avg(avgs) as avgbefore
FROM
Averages
WHERE year < 1980) as Before,

(SELECT avg(avgs) as avgafter
FROM
Averages
WHERE year >= 1980) as After
```

Comment: Only a question. You have agree this: My answers to homework, quizzes and exams will be my own work.
I will not post or discuss the solutions to homeworks, quizzes or exams until after the answers have been released by the instructors.
I will not engage in any other activities that will dishonestly improve my results or dishonestly improve/hurt the results of others. ??

Comment: @danihp The Prof has specifically said in her screenside chats that we can discuss the homeworks as long as we're not blatantly copying. She doesn't agree with the cookie cutter honor code. Also, I've already gotten the right answer. My "scores" won't be improved, not that they matter.

Comment: ok @saccharine, I wish you to become a good dba. Be careful with your first query because is a cross join. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Comment: @danihp Is there a better way to do it? I was under the impression that the cross joins were optimized into theta joins by SQL. Also, it fits better with relational algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if SQLite supports the ANSI CASE statement, but if it does try the following:

```
SELECT avgbefore - avgafter
FROM ( 
    SELECT avg(CASE WHEN year < 1980 THEN avgs ELSE null END) as avgbefore,
           avg(CASE WHEN year >= 1980 THEN avgs ELSE null END) as avgafter
    FROM averages
) t
```

This uses the fact that NULL values are not taken into account by aggregate functions.

Comment: What's the meaning of the little t at the end of yoru code? I've just checked, and CASE is supported, though I was hoping for something that used more of the basic commands.

Comment: @saccharine: the `t` is an alias for the derived table (inner select). The ANSI standard requires that. Not sure if SQLIte does as well. Try it without the alias. I don't think the statement can be more basic than that. Why do you think CASE is not a "basic" command?

Comment: Well, CASE was never actually taught. Instead, the videos usually emphasized subqueries within the SELECT, FROM, and WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same query you already have with the slight change that it calculates on the sub queries directly instead of using a from clause creating derived tables. It does not deal with using the table `averages` in multiple places but it is perhaps a bit more readable.

```
SELECT (SELECT AVG(avgs)
        FROM   averages
        WHERE  YEAR < 1980) - (SELECT AVG(avgs)
                               FROM   averages
                               WHERE  YEAR >= 1980)
```